# Link giving error in editor

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am trying to tidy up a header in netbeans 8.0 which I am using as part of a view. The editor is underlining:

```
<link href="<?=base_url('css/bootstrap.css')"></link>
```

Please see screenshot. Why? what am I doing wrong?

The full code for my header is:

```
<head>
<base href="<?=base_url();?>">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Your Contacts</title>
<meta name="description" content="manage your contacts with name, email and phone">
<meta name="author" content="yubi4dition">
<!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
<!-- Le styles -->

<link href="<?=base_url('css/bootstrap.css')"></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ></link>
<link href="<?=base_url('css/yourcontacts.css')?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ></link>

<link href="<?=base_url('css/font-awesome.css')?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ></link>

<link href="<?=base_url('css/tablesorter.css')?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ></link>

<!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
<link href="<?=base_url('css/ico/favicon.ico')?>" rel="shortcut icon" ></link>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>



</head>
```

Comment: Are you using a template engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<link href="<?=base_url('css/bootstrap.css') ?>"></link>
```

you seem to lack the closing tag.

Answer (score 2):

Missing the closing PHP tag :)